# Discord.py variables not constant throughout the code

Tags: python, json, variables, discord.py, bots

I am currently developing a bot using discord.py and in this case using a JSON file to store the bots prefixes for each server that it is in.
( + is the bots default prefix )
With prefixes, there is 4 things I am doing:
On guild join: Adds a prefix to the JSON document
On guild remove: Removes the prefix for this guild from the JSON document
+changeprefix 
and when the bot is mentioned, it outputs a message stating:
'Hello, the prefix for this server is +'

The first 3 parts work correctly. However, when the bot is mentioned it outputs the error:

```py
await message.channel.send(f'Hi my prefix for this server is **{prefix}**)
NameError: name 'prefix' is not defined
```

I have done some research and asked multiple help servers about this issue however what I have found is that python does not have constants which would be useful in this situation and people on  help servers were unsure of the answer to this question.

The code for all parts of the prefix setup is this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '+'
    prefixes = prefix

    with open('prefix.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

# REMOVES PREFIX FROM JSON FILE
@bot.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

    with open('prefix.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

# COMMAND TO CHANGE THE PREFIX
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def changeprefix(ctx, prefix):
    with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix
    prefix = prefix

    with open('prefix.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f'Prefix changed to **{prefix}**')
```

The `on_message` where the error is coming from is this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("<@bot ID>"):
        await message.channel.send(f'Hi my prefix for this server is **{prefix}**')
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

and this is further down in the code than the other parts of this

Any help would be appreciated.
The expected output is so when the bot it tagged, it sends a message saying the current prefix for the server.

**Update**
As mentioned in a comment below, I have updated my code so it reads the JSON file and retrieves the prefix. This is the updated code in the `on_message`event

```
if message.content.startswith("<bot ID>"):
        with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)
            prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix
            await message.channel.send(f'Hi my prefix for this server is **{prefix}**')
```

However, this is still showing the

```
NameError: name 'prefix' is not defined
```

**Other things I have tried**
I also tried defining `prefix` like this:

```
if message.content.startswith("<@850794452364951554>"):
        with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)
            prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix
            prefix = prefix
            await message.channel.send(f'Hi my prefix for this server is **{prefix}**')
```

I tried the line `prefix = prefix` both before and after the line `prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix`

In both those cases, it outputs this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prefix' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: `prefix` has to be defined, what the error says... Just because you used it in another `command` you can't use it in an `on_message` event again. Open the JSON file, load the `prefixes` and display it.

Comment: @Dominik I have just tried doing that and updated the question with what I have tried, however, I am still getting errors.

Comment: What is `prefixes = prefix`? Gives me an error (`prefix`). Also: Why do you add a prefix if the bot joins a guild? I see no advantage in it.

Comment: @Dominik `prefixes = prefix` was an attempt to define prefix when the error showed. I add the prefix on guild join so that the bot has a default prefix and can then be changed with a command. There is not a default prefix set here: `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, intents=intents)` and it retrieves the prefix from the JSON file so I assumed it needs the prefix added  on guild join to function.

Comment: I will edit my answer and add another way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense to me in many places, because you use `ctx` in a `message` event, which is not possible at first. Also, when copying the code, I get an error with `prefixes = prefix`, so it is questionable why this supposedly works for you.

Your `on_guild_join` also makes no sense to me, because everyone has the default prefix. The event may be relevant for your `changeprefix` command, but that can be done better.

I rewrote your `changeprefix` command a bit and adjusted your `on_message` event.

**Take a look at the following code:**

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("What is the prefix for this guild?"):
        with open('prefix.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
            custom_prefixes = json.load(fp)
        try:
            prefix = custom_prefixes[f"{message.guild.id}"] 
            await message.channel.send(f'Hi my prefix for this server is **{prefix}**')
        except KeyError:
            return await message.channel.send("You have not set a new prefix.") # No JSON entry

    await bot.process_commands(message)


@bot.command()
async def setprefix(ctx, prefixes: str):
    with open('prefix.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        custom_prefixes = json.load(fp)

    try:
        custom_prefixes[f"{ctx.guild.id}"] = prefixes # If the guild.id already exists
    except KeyError: # If there is no JSON entry
        new = {ctx.guild.id: prefixes} # New prefix with command input
        custom_prefixes.update(new) # Add guild.id and prefix

    await ctx.send(f"Prefix set to: `{prefixes}`")

    with open('prefix.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fpp:
        json.dump(custom_prefixes, fpp, indent=2)
```

As your `on_guild_join` event also contains errors we have to determine the prefix in a different way. We can achieve that if we append the set `prefix` to the default one.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
def determine_prefix(bot, msg):
    guild = msg.guild
    base = [DEFAULT_PREFIX]

    with open('prefix.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp: # Open the JSON
        custom_prefixes = json.load(fp) # Load the custom prefixes

    if guild: # If the guild exists
        try:
            prefix = custom_prefixes[f"{guild.id}"] # Get the prefix
            base.append(prefix) # Append the new prefix
        except KeyError:
            pass

    return base

[...](command.prefix = determine_prefix) # Where you defined your bot
```

Comment: So where is DEFAULT_PREFIX defined?