# discord py - Custom command prefix doesn't work (no command run)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

i have a problem that i can't solve. I'm trying to add a prefix switcher for all guilds, that uses my bot. So I've done that, but currently no command get's triggered and I can't find a solution since hours. Its really frustrating.

```
import os
import json
import discord.ext
from discord.ext import commands

#from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
#from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_option, create_choice

# Prefix-Wechsler
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open("prefix.json", "r") as f:
        prefix = json.load(f)

    return prefix(str(message.guild.id))

##### Wichtige Bot-Einstellungen ######
intents = discord.Intents().default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=str(get_prefix), intents=intents)
bot.remove_command('help')

# slash = SlashCommand(bot, override_type = True, sync_on_cog_reload=True, sync_commands=True)

### Server-Join ###
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):

    with open("prefix.json", "r") as f:
        prefix = json.load(f)

    prefix[str(guild.id)] = "="

    with open("prefix.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefix, f)


### Aktionen für den Bot-Start ###
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('  ____  _ _  _       _    _ _     _   ')
    print(' |  _ \| | || |     | |  | (_)   | |  ')
    print(' | |_) | | || |_ ___| | _| |_ ___| |_ ')
    print(' |  _ <| |__   _/ __| |/ / | / __| __|')
    print(' | |_) | |  | || (__|   <| | \__ \ |_ ')
    print(' |____/|_|  |_| \___|_|\_\_|_|___/\__|')
    print('                                      ')
    print(f'Entwickelt von Yannic | {bot.user.name}')
    print('────────────')

# Prefix-Wechsler
@bot.command(aliases=["changeprefix", "Setprefix", "Changeprefix"])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@commands.bot_has_permissions(read_messages=True, read_message_history=True, send_messages=True, attach_files=True, embed_links=True)
async def setprefix(ctx, prefix):
    if prefix is None:
        return await ctx.reply('› `` - **Prefix vergessen**: Du hast vergessen, einen neuen Prefix anzugeben! <a:pepe_delete:725444707781574737>')

    with open("prefix.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

    with open("prefix.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f)

    await ctx.reply(f'› Mein Bot-Prefix wurde erfolgreich auf `{prefix}` geändert! <a:WISCHEN_2:860466698566107149>')


def load_all():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')


load_all()

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

And that's my task for checking if all bot guilds are in the prefix file (in another cog):

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=10)
```

async def prefix_check(self):
await self.client.wait_until_ready()

```
        for guild in self.client.guilds:
            with open("prefix.json", "r") as f:
                prefix = json.load(f)

            if guild.id not in prefix:

                prefix[str(guild.id)] = "="

                with open("prefix.json", "w") as f:
                    json.dump(prefix, f)
```

Comment: I made an answer to that a while ago. Is this helping you? [Discord.py variables not constant throughout the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67863823/discord-py-variables-not-constant-throughout-the-code/67864467#67864467)

Comment: Not really. Because i need the on guild join and the prefix_check to set a default prefix. I'm confused.

Comment: Why would you need the `on_guild_join`-event? You're making it too complicated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are making this way too complicated. Your `on_guild_join` event can be omitted completely, you just need to make some adjustments for it.

*Also, my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67863823/discord-py-variables-not-constant-throughout-the-code/67864467#67864467) would have helped you if you had looked at it a bit.*

Based on that and adapted a bit to you here is a **possible answer:**

```py
TOKEN = "YourToken"

DEFAULT_PREFIX = "-" # The prefix you want everyone to have if you don't define your own

def determine_prefix(bot, msg):
    guild = msg.guild
    base = [DEFAULT_PREFIX]

    with open('prefix.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:  # Open the JSON
        custom_prefixes = json.load(fp) # Load the custom prefixes

    if guild:  # If the guild exists
        try:
            prefix = custom_prefixes[f"{guild.id}"] # Get the prefix
            base.append(prefix) # Append the new prefix
        except KeyError:
            pass

    return base

intents = discord.Intents.all() # import all intents if enabled
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=determine_prefix, intents=intents) # prefix is our function

@bot.command()
async def setprefix(ctx, prefixes: str):
    with open('prefix.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        custom_prefixes = json.load(fp) # load the JSON file

    try:
        custom_prefixes[f"{ctx.guild.id}"] = prefixes # If the guild is in the JSON
    except KeyError:  # If no entry for the guild exists
        new = {ctx.guild.id: prefixes}
        custom_prefixes.update(new) # Add the new prefix for the guild

    await ctx.send(f"Prefix wurde zu `{prefixes}` geändert.")

    with open('prefix.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fpp:
        json.dump(custom_prefixes, fpp, indent=2) # Change the new prefix
```

**To show that it works:**

[image]