# Python: Nextcord Bot custom prefix not displaying properly

Tags: python, discord, bots, prefix, nextcord

this is my first question here and I hope that I'll find an answer for my problem.

Situation:
I'm not a programmer but I'm currently learning python (interesting and fun). I looked for interesting projects to do with python (i'm open to suggestions and recommendations! :) ) and I stumbled across a Discord Bot. I started watching tutorials and started coding. I know the basics of python so it's easy to understand most of the things. My bot basically works. Now i wanted to add custom prefixes for different servers. I researched and then wrote the code. The .json file is correctly adjusted and saved. Every discord should be able to set a custom prefix.

My Problem:
If I change the prefix and type (prefix = !) "!help" it shows: "<function get_prefix at 0x000001AC7DAD45E0>help" at my custom help and NOT the prefix.
{bot.command_prefix} is not stating the prefix.

My Code:

```py
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from nextcord import Embed
import json

# Token for the Discord-Bot
TOKEN = '<not showing here>'

# Declaring intents which are necessary
intents = nextcord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

# Create a Bot instance
bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents)

# Define the get_prefix function
def get_prefix(bot, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes.get(str(message.guild.id), '!')  # Default to '!' if no prefix is set

# Set the command prefix using the command_prefix parameter when creating the Bot instance
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '!'

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@bot.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@bot.command()
async def changeprefix(ctx, prefix: str):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
        
bot.remove_command("help")

# Starting the bpt
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(status=nextcord.Status.do_not_disturb, activity=nextcord.Game('nothing'))
    print(f'{bot.user} is now running!')
    print("------------------------------")

# Define a custom error handler
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send(f"Not a valid command. Use {bot.command_prefix}help for a list of available commands.")

# Custom help
@bot.command(name="help", brief="Shows this window")
async def custom_help(ctx, *args):
    if not args:
        # Sort the commands alphabetically, help always at the top
        sorted_commands = sorted(bot.commands, key=lambda x: (x.name != "help", x.name))
        # No arguments provided, show a list of top-level commands
        embed = Embed(color=0x0080ff, title="Available Commands")
        for command in sorted_commands:
            if not command.hidden:
                description = command.brief or "No desc. yet."
                embed.add_field(name=f"{bot.command_prefix}{command.name}", value=description, inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    elif len(args) == 1:
        # One argument provided, show command description if available
        command_name = args[0]
        command = bot.get_command(command_name)
        if command:
            embed = Embed(color=0x0080ff, title=f"Help for {bot.command_prefix}{command.name}")
            embed.description = command.help
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"Command not found: {command_name}")
    elif len(args) == 2:
        # Two arguments provided, show subcommand description if available
        command_name, subcommand_name = args
        command = bot.get_command(f"{command_name} {subcommand_name}")
        if command:
            embed = Embed(color=0x0080ff, title=f"Help for {bot.command_prefix}{command.name}")
            embed.description = command.help
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"Subcommand not found: {bot.command_prefix}{command_name} {subcommand_name}")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Invalid usage. Use {bot.command_prefix}help to list commands, {bot.command_prefix}help command to see command details, or {bot.command_prefix}help command subcommand to see subcommand details.")

# Run the bot
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

[a picture of the problem: not showing the prefix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh9kG.png)

Any thoughts or ideas are appreciated!

What I tried:
I have been trying to research for a solution why it outputs the function and not the value. I've tried adjusting different things and I've used chatgpt to try to fix the problem. Unfortunately, all this did not help .

Comment: Do the following questions/answers help you to understand what went wrong? (*Especially on how to retrieve and save the prefix*) | [discord py - Custom command prefix doesn't work (no command run)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323335/discord-py-custom-command-prefix-doesnt-work-no-command-run/68323464#68323464) & [Show data from .json in Discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69001758/show-data-from-json-in-discord-py/69003443#69003443)

Comment: @Dominik Thank you for your answer! I have read through and looked at everything in detail and I understand it a bit better now. I have also tried to adjust my code accordingly, but the problem persists. My commands work but it still doesn't show the prefix but prints as <function determine_prefix at 0x...>setprefix when i type "!help"

I want that: "await ctx.send(f" {bot.command_prefix}help") prints: "!help" and not: "<function determine_prefix at 0x...>help"  :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access a “parameter” inside your `bot` definition.

Assuming, that a server set their prefix, you can use the following code:

```py
def get_prefix(bot, msg: discord.Message):
    guild = msg.guild
    base = ["!"]

    with open('prefixes.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        prefixes  = json.load(fp)

    if guild:
        try:
            prefix = prefixes[str(guild.id)]
            base.append(prefix)
        except KeyError:
            pass

    return base
```

This method can be used to load all the prefix into the bot.

- Our "base" is the default prefix, just in case the server did not set a prefix
- We open the JSON file and try to access the prefix for the guild (`msg.guild`)
- Our last step is to append the prefix and then return the base, which is either the default prefix or the one set for the guild

Moving on, how you can retrieve the prefix is pretty easy:

```py
prefix = get_prefix(bot, ctx.message)[1]
```

Please note that there's no error handler included, please do that yourself (*Just in case the JSON is empty or any other case*)

Here, we use our defined function from the beginning again.

You can then work with the code above in the rest of your code:

```py
for command in commands:
    embed.add_field(name=f"{prefix}{command.name}", value=command.help, inline=False)
```

- Here we put the set prefix in front of the command name
- Our `value` field returns the docstring description of your command

This will return the set prefix for the guild. Once again: There's no error handler included in my part.